# std lib objects as return types and function parameters

Tags: c++, oop, header-files, std

I am new to C++ and the idea of header files defining classes is foreign to me. I have the following header file for a Polynomial class that is giving me a lot of errors.

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

class Polynomial {
public:
    Polynomial(std::vector <int>&);
    Polynomial(const Polynomial& orig);
    virtual ~Polynomial();

    std::vector <int> getCoeffs();
    Polynomial getIntegral(int, int, int);
    Polynomial getDerivative(int);
    std::string toString();

    void integrate(int, int);
    void derive();
private:
    std::vector<int> coeffs;
};

 #endif /* POLYNOMIAL_H */
```

All of the class methods that include something from the standard lib in their return type definition give me the error: 'vector' (or 'string') in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Also the constructor which takes a vector as a parameter gives the error: expected ')' before '<' token.

I'm sure this is something very obvious, but whatever it is the tutorials I have done haven't gone this deep into classes and class definitions to come across an example like this.

Comment: You need to include the appropriate header to use the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` is defined in the header *vector*. You need to add the statement

```
#include <vector>
```

at the top of your header file. This causes the preprocessor to (effectively) paste the contents of that file in place of the `#include` statement. Thus the compiler knows what the type `std::vector` refers to in your class definition.

The same applies to `std::string`, which is, in turn, defined in the header *string*. So add `#include <string>` for that header.

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) is a good reference to search for types and their respective headers; it is also a good online reference in general for C++.

This is what your header file should look like:

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Polynomial {
  ...
};

#endif /* POLYNOMIAL_H */
```

Comment: Thanks, I sometimes get confused on when it is appropriate to include different things; for example, why do you typically not include cpp files but you do include header files?